# How can I print in black & white?

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2013

I am trying to print in black and white in Microsoft Word 2013, however I cannot find any dialogue box in the printing screen that gives this option?

Answer (score 6):

That is a property of the printer.

When you choose to print, do not select `Quick Print`. Use the printer dialog and adjust print properties there. Somewhere in there is a choice to print in Grayscale.

Not sure what you're using but this is what mine looks like.

[image]

Comment: oh brother. for some reason my printer doesn't have any such dialog in windows (it does under OS X!), and it's out of color ink so it refuses to print a text document which has no color because it's not explicitly able to be told to print b&w.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, printing preferences aren't specific to a program and you may need to go to `Printer Properties` to get when you are looking for.  I can't say how to do if for your specific printer since most settings dialogues are set up differently (edit: As demonstrated by mine vs @CharlieRB), here is how mine looks:

[image]

Then the Printer Properties (this is an old HP):

[image]

Comment: For me, I had to go under advanced settings and then it was a checkbox.